# Swift 2 to 3 Migration Core Data NSManagedObject Class

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, swift3, ios10

I have the following code for one of my tables.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InventoryTableCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! InventoryTableViewCell

        let inventory : Inventory = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Inventory
        cell.inventoryItem = inventory

        cell.drawCell() //uses passed inventoryItem to draw it's self accordingly.

        return cell
    }
```

I'm getting a runtime error on `cell.inventoryItem = inventory`

It says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class )

It didn't do this in swift 2 so not sure what the error is.  I'll take a screenshot of my model and created class.

I have no idea how to fix the error since this worked before.  What changed?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know whether you have initialised the variable "inventoryItem" in "InventoryTableViewCell" class. If you have initiated this, then please change that to optional variable. It may cause also the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved my issue, when you define the items you have to give a context to it now or it won't work.

On code that I did not show here for my InventoryTableViewCell I had defined inventoryItem incorrectly.

Here is the correct way to do it.

```
//Set inventory item as an InventoryType within the correct context
    var inventoryItem = Inventory(context: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext)
```